# MySQL issue: LEFT JOIN on empty table

Tags: mysql, left-join

Given a database with two tables `X` and `Y`, I have a query that should `LEFT JOIN` the two tables on attributes `X.a1` and `Y.b1`.  I used the following query:

```
SELECT X.a1, X.a2, Y.b1, Y.b2 FROM X LEFT JOIN Y ON (X.a1 = Y.b1)
```

I thought that would be good enough to work, even if `Y` is currently an empty table.  However, the query breaks because table `Y` is empty, it seems.  Is there any way to reformat this query so that even if `Y` is an empty table, the `LEFT JOIN` will not break?  Or do I just need to always make sure that there is some data in table `Y`, even if it doesn't match anything in table `X` (hence the `LEFT JOIN`).

Comment: Sorry, I edited the tables to make more sense.  I had an idea in my head and messed it up.

Comment: I had a similar problem, and poh's solution below worked for me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your table names are a little confusing.  Is it X and Y, or X.a and Y.b?

If X and Y:

```
SELECT X.a1, X.a2, Y.a1, Y.b2 FROM X LEFT OUTER JOIN Y ON (X.a1 = Y.b1)
```

should bring back all X, with nulls for the Y.a1 and Y.b2 where there is no matching record.

Comment: do you know any other left joins? :) LEFT JOIN = LEFT OUTER JOIN

Comment: @Andrey IMO 'OUTER' should be used in **outer** joins regardless of the RDBMS' shortcuts.

Comment: i agree, but i think it doesn't make sense in current problem

Comment: I fixed the problems that I was having with the table names.  Sorry about that, I messed up my example.  But yeah, LEFT JOIN is the same as LEFT OUTER JOIN, so even if I used the shortcut, that shouldn't be the problem, I'd think.

Comment: @ashays so are you still experiencing the issue even after updating your query in your question?

Comment: Yeah, the query is just a generalized form of the actual query that I used.  It's on a server that I have access to back at the office, but not here, so I generalized it to ask here.

Answer (score 13):

Since you didn't post your actual SQL, i just make assumption here. My experience telling me that you might have a where clause that causes the SQL to return empty set.

```
SELECT X.a1, X.a2, Y.b1, Y.b2 FROM X LEFT JOIN Y ON (X.a1 = Y.b1)
WHERE Y.b3 = 'something'
```

The above SQL will return empty result set. You may need to modify your SQL into the following format, by bring up the problematic where clause to LEFT JOIN ON clause.

```
SELECT X.a1, X.a2, Y.b1, Y.b2 FROM X 
LEFT JOIN Y ON (X.a1 = Y.b1 and Y.b3 = 'something')
```

Comment: Thank you, I had a similar issue and this fixed it!

Comment: Just to be clear - this will not actually filter the results based on Y 'something'; it will return a result set that has NULL for all Y 'something'.

Comment: Why does adding `Y.b3 = 'something'` inside the `ON` clause work, whereas having it in the `where` clause doesn't? I've seen it before but don't get it

Answer (score 0):

Try your query on some Sql editor that returns errors like
HeidiSQL or similar. In my case the problem was ambiguous id in WHERE clause.