# Why doesn't MySQL call a function correct in a Query with left outer join inside a where condition

Tags: mysql, sql

**This problem is not present in MariaDB 10.6 anymore.**

We have a problem with outer join and a function call inside a where condition. It seems that the function is not called if the outer join don't find records in the outer table.

In real the function are more complex this is simplify by eample to demonstrate the problem.

Simple Test Returns nothing, but 1 record would be correct:

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT 1 ID) t1
LEFT JOIN (SELECT 1 ID, null as date FROM (SELECT 1) x WHERE 1=2) t2 ON t2.ID=t1.ID
WHERE
IS_LOWHIGH_DATE(t2.date)
```

Complex Test also returns nothing, but one record would be correct:

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT 1 ID1, cast(null as date) as date1 ) t1
LEFT JOIN (SELECT 2 ID2, cast(null as date) as date2) t2 ON t2.ID2=t1.ID1
WHERE
IS_LOWHIGH_DATE(t2.date2)
```

Return one record with correct results:

```
SELECT *, IS_LOWHIGH_DATE(NULL), IS_LOWHIGH_DATE(t1.date1), IS_LOWHIGH_DATE(current_date)
FROM (SELECT CAST(NULL as date) as date1) t1
```

Should by return two records but don't do that, only one line returns:

```
SELECT t1.*, IS_LOWHIGH_DATE(t1.date1), NULL, NULL
FROM (SELECT 1 ID1, cast(null as date) as date1 ) t1
UNION ALL
SELECT t1.*, IS_LOWHIGH_DATE(t1.date1), t2.*
FROM (SELECT 1 ID1, cast(null as date) as date1 ) t1
LEFT JOIN (SELECT 2 ID2, cast(null as date) as date2) t2 ON t2.ID2=t1.ID1
WHERE
IS_LOWHIGH_DATE(t2.date2)
```

This works with coalesce() arround the attribute:

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT 1 ID) t1
LEFT JOIN (SELECT 1 ID, null as date FROM (SELECT 1) x WHERE 1=2) t2 ON t2.ID=t1.ID
WHERE
IS_LOWHIGH_DATE(COALESCE(t2.date))
```

Simple test with dummy return value (doesn't matter)

```
CREATE FUNCTION is_lowhigh_date
 (p_date date) RETURNS tinyint(1)
  NO SQL DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
 RETURN true;
END
```

The function at is

```
CREATE FUNCTION is_lowhigh_date
 (p_date date) RETURNS tinyint(1)
  NO SQL DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
 RETURN CASE 
   WHEN p_date is NULL OR p_date <= '0001-01-01' or p_date >= '9999-12-31' THEN
     true
 ELSE
   false
 END;
END
```

You can try sqlfiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/513671/6

Comment: It's not much of a function, is it? Do you really need it to be a function - or, to put it another way, does its being a function offer some kind of benefit?

Comment: @Frank . . . This looks like a bug -- some sort of optimization might be bypassing the `where` clause.

Comment: "(SELECT CAST(NULL as date) as date1)....Should by return 2 Lines". If by lines you mean records, then no, it shouldn't.

Comment: @symcbean not the result bevor, the next...

Comment: @Gordon... Thanks, but this is no good news ... :-)

Comment: @Frank . . . Well, there is a mechanism for reporting bugs (https://bugs.mysql.com/), although you should search existing bugs first.  And, it will probably be fixed, in less than a decade.  ;)

Comment: did you try to `EXPLAIN` you very first query sample?

Answer (score 0):

This will give you your expected result (avoiding the empty set caused by the last where)

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT 1 ID) t1
LEFT JOIN (SELECT 1 ID, null as date FROM (SELECT 1) x WHERE 1=2) t2
ON (t2.ID=t1.ID AND IS_LOWHIGH_DATE(t2.date))
```

Comment: Thanks guido, but I can't grant that all users never use this function in a where condition...

Comment: The problem is not your function, it is the empty set returned by the impossible where clause (look at the query plan using explain), so it is a problem for who writes queries using any function; see @kordirko answer and also read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2373259/mysql-issue-left-join-on-empty-table (pho answer).

Answer (score 0):

Run these commands:

```
explain extended
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT 1 ID) t1
LEFT JOIN (SELECT 1 ID, null as date FROM (SELECT 1) x WHERE 1=2) t2 ON t2.ID=t1.ID
WHERE
IS_LOWHIGH_DATE(t2.date)
;
show warnings;
```

this will give you your query after optimalizaltion

```
/* select#1 */ select '1' AS `ID`,NULL AS `ID`,NULL AS `date` 
from (/* select#3 */ select 1 AS `ID`,NULL AS `date` 
from (/* select#4 */ select 1 AS `1`) `x` where 0) `t2` where 0
```

The last `WHERE 0` means `WHERE false` => MySql doesn't execute this query at all, so the subquery nor function in the subquery are not executed too.